# Launch Window on Windows startup

Tags: c#, wpf, startup

I want that my application (a WPF `Window`) is launched on Windows startup. I tried different solutions, but no one seems to work. What i have to write in my code to do this?

Comment: What are the solutions you have tried?

Comment: I tried to write a key registry: HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Comment: And do you have any logging? In any case, what do you store in the registry key? That solution should work.

Comment: Yes, I hav to log, this is my code:  `RegistryKey app = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("HKCU\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
            app.SetValue("timer", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);`

Comment: BaseDirectory? You also need to include the executable you wish to start. BaseDirectory just returns the directory, it does not include the exe itself.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are correct when you say that you must add a key to the registry.

Add a key to:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

if you want to start the application for the current user.

Or:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

If you want to start it for all users.

For example, starting the application for the current user:

```
var path = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run";
RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(path, true);
key.SetValue("MyApplication", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
```

Just replace the line second line with

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(path, true);
```

if you want to automatically start the application for all users on Windows startup.

Just remove the registry value if you no longer want to start the application automatically.

As such:

```
var path = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run";
RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(path, true);
key.DeleteValue("MyApplication", false);
```

This sample code was tested for a WinForms app. If you need to determine the path to the executable for a WPF app, then give the following a try.

```
string path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
```

Just replace "Application.ExecutablePath.ToString()" with the path to your executable.

Comment: [Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application_members(v=vs.90)) has not ExecutablePath.

Comment: This sample code is for a Windows Forms application. You need to get the path to the executable in a different manner for WPF apps.

Comment: It works! If I want to remove this behavior, have I to remove the key? Could you show me how?

Comment: Idd, you only have to remove the key. I've already included this in my answer.

Comment: Where does this code needs to be written for a WPF application?

Comment: In my case it was add into startup (visible in TaskManager), but with "Disabled" status