# Launch wpf Application on Windows startup

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I have developed a WPF application, now I have to launch the application on windows startup. 
To do this, I have written the below code. I got the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065139/launch-window-on-windows-startup). 
It is adding the key in registry but not launching the application.

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
string str = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
key.SetValue("Camaleone", str);
```

Comment: when the application starts it will have the working directory C:\windows\System32. make sure any references to files it needs are looking in the right directory

Comment: meaning??please explain it.

Comment: Where is placed the code snippet in your application? Because if it is not in the main(executable) assembly it wouldn't work.

Comment: it is placed in the main window.

Comment: Another idea, does your application need administrator rights to run, if so it might be stopped by UAC, depending on os.

Comment: No application doesn't needed administrator rights

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you start an application normally by double clicking, the working directory is normally the path of the exe file.
This means if you reference any settings files in your code it can find them.

But, when you add it to the registry to run on startup, the working directory is `c:\windows\system32` because it is started by windows itself.

I normally use this:

```
public static string BaseDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

this means that `BaseDir` is now the path to the exe.

Whenever I reference any files, eg a settings file I would use:

```
string mySettingsFile = Path.Combine(BaseDir, "MySettingsFile.xml");
```

Comment: In your case you can just set the [Environment.CurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Be careful with Environment.CurrentDirectory it returns the working directory, so you could end up in the same boat.