# How to make autorun in C# when registry doesnt work

Tags: c#, autorun

I can see the app in registers but it wont startup.

```
RegistryKey rkApp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true); // Add the value in the registry so that the application runs at startup 
rkApp.SetValue("WindowsSelfRepairTool", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```

This is the code I copied from internet, it gets my application to registers because I can see it "On startup" in task manager as well as in the registry editor. But for some reason, when I restart the computer the app wont start.
Also I tried this code in Console App and added code `Process.Launch("..")` to launch the WPF one. Console starts successfuly but it doesnt run the WPF.. Any help?

Comment: Possible cause: [Launch wpf Application on Windows startup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21348394/724039),

Comment: My first suggestion would be to check and make sure that the path in the registry is set correctly. Not sure but `Location` might be just the path without the file name?

Comment: When the value `Location` contains, one or more, spaces, you might need to add double quotes around the value.