# Wpf application doesn't start at startup

Tags: wpf, autostart, internet-connection

I have developed a wpf app and want it to run whenever the computer starts up.However I have been unable to do so......I have tried editing registry like this answer...

[Launch Window on Windows startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065139/launch-window-on-windows-startup][1])

**Interesting thing is the app does autostart when there is internet connection.It doesn't when there is no internet. I do need internet connection at some point of time to sync the data to internet application.** However this should not have affected the startup of the application.

Any ideas???

Comment: Your app is starting ... but quit (when there is no internet connection) before the first window was shown.

Comment: @SirRufo Exactly...I think so that too...What may be the reason behind it? Can I have a solution?

Comment: @Annonymousprogrammer Are you able to start the application manually without internet?

Comment: Yes....I am able to

Comment: Well, how can we say anything about your application without seeing any code?

Comment: Thank you @SirRufo for pointing that out......It was a mistake from my side...In the future I will take it into consideration about the questions that I ask....:)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can set up a timer, and after several minutes, check out your internet, if the internet is ok, then run your application continuely. If not, reset the timer, and check again.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the run line (Windows + R). Type "shell:common startup" press "enter". Place a shortcut in that folder and restart your machine (depending on what the *.exe is doing you may need to set its properties to run as administrator).